# False True change attr by onclick jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, toggle, attr

I need to change data attribute "aria-selected" by oncklick.
But this script does not work. Could you help me, please?

```
<a href="#" aria-selected="true" resource="">SHOW/HIDE</a>
```

And here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($){
  $("a").attr("aria-selected","false");
  $(" ul li a").addClass("accordion");

  $('.accordion').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('aria-selected')) {
      $(this).attr("aria-selected","true");
    } 
    else {
      $(this).attr("aria-selected", "false");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `aria-selected` is a string... Not a boolean.
So you have to compare it with a string.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($){
  $("a").attr("aria-selected","false");
  $(" ul li a").addClass("accordion");

  $('.accordion').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('aria-selected') == "false") {  // Change is here.
      $(this).attr("aria-selected","true");
    } 
    else {
      $(this).attr("aria-selected", "false");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($(this).attr('aria-selected')) {
```

is supposed to be

```
if ( !$(this).attr('aria-selected') ) {
```

You are explicitly setting `aria-selected` to false on page load. When the element with `accordion` class is clicked, you seem to toggle the attribute value. But in your case it will always be set to false, cause of your existing `if` condition.

You can modify the code to make it a bit cleaner

```js
$("a").attr("aria-selected", "false");
$(" ul li a").addClass("accordion");

$('.accordion').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var $this = $(this);
  var currentValue = $this.attr('aria-selected');
  
  $this.attr('aria-selected', !(currentValue === 'true'));
});
```

```css
[aria-selected="true"] {
  color: green;
}

[aria-selected="false"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
  <a href="#" aria-selected="true" resource="">SHOW/HIDE</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#" aria-selected="true" resource="">SHOW/HIDE</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#" aria-selected="true" resource="">SHOW/HIDE</a>
</li>
</ul>
```