# Show/hide div click on link jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm finalizing a webpage, this: https://www.landingpagedude.ca/automate

And I would like to know how I can get the user to click on the 'Click here' link in the 'Speakers' section:
[image]

The second section is displayed below the first, also called 'Speakers' above the section that is displayed first:
[image]

So in case the second section 'Speakers' would be hidden. Clicking on the 'Back to speakers' link would return to the first section 'Speakers'

Answer (score 1):

So I toyed with your page a little, and having jQuery right in there made making those changes a breeze for my session. I simply opened up the console and typed two lines:

```
$("#speakers-info ul a").on("click", function(){ 
  $("#speakers-info").hide(); 
  $("#speakers").show();
}); /* It was a one-liner, as shown below */

$("#speakers ul a").on("click", function(){ $("#speakers").hide(); $("#speakers-info").show(); })
```

The first takes the "Return to Speakers" link, and uses that to hide the current div and show the Speakers div. The second reverses the operation. For your own use, simply put those two lines in your custom.js file, pretty much anywhere.

Of course, you may want to hide the #speakers-info by default.

Comment: Perfect! That's what I was looking for. Thank you so much for that!

Answer (score 0):

look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769223/false-true-change-attr-by-onclick-jquery) to use any attribute as `aria-selected` changing `true/false` to show current element details

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.click(...)` or `.on("click", ...)`, `.hide()` and `.show()` to make this work. Here's the code you'll need.

```js
$("#speakers-info").hide();
$(".expand-content-link").click(function() {
  $("#speakers").hide();
  $("#speakers-info").show();
});
$(".txtAlg-speakerInfo span a").click(function() {
  $("#speakers-info").hide();
  $("#speakers").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="speakers">
List of Speakers.
<a href="#" class="expand-content-link">Click Here</a>
</div>
<div id="speakers-info" style="display:none;">
Speaker Info.
<li class="txtAlg-speakerInfo span a"><span><a href="#">Back to Speakers</a></span></li>
</div>
```